# Trying to convert categorical data to numeric and run RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I'm testing this code:

```
df1 = df[['Group', 'Sector', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat4', 'Cat5', 'Cat6', 'Industry', 'Market', 'Price']].copy()
df1 = df1[:100000]
df1.shape

df1 = df1.fillna(0)


df1 = pd.get_dummies(df1)


X = df1.drop(['Price'], axis=1)
y = df1['Price']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Split dataset into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3) # 70% training and 30% test


#Import Random Forest Model
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# Create the model with 100 trees
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, 
                               bootstrap = True,
                               max_features = 'sqrt')
# Fit on training data
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I'm getting an error on this line: `model.fit(X_train, y_train)`

This is my error: `ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'`

My setup is like this: I have many fields in 'df' and I am copying a few to 'df1'.  These are all categorical: `'Group', 'Sector', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat4', 'Cat5', 'Cat6', 'Industry', 'Market'`

This one is numeric: `'Price'`

I am using one-hot encoding to convert the categorical items to numeric items and the numeric (Price) stays as it is.  Is there something wrong with this setup, or is it fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a **classifier** to predict continuous prices. When it refers to the *label*, `sklearn` means the target, so the problem is not your `X`, it's the `y`. What you need is `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor`. With this, you will be able to predict continuous values, such as `price`.

Use this instead:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, 
                               bootstrap = True,
                               max_features = 'sqrt')
# model.fit(X, y...
```

Comment: Ok, I see what's happening here.  I dropped the continuous variable.  Let's say I want to predict 'Market', based on all the other features, and I definitely want to use Classification, not Regression.  As soon as I set 'Market' to the y-variable and then apply one-hot encoding, I get all different Market-variables, because of the one-hot encoding.  How can I make this concept work?

Comment: Use the classifier and encode your categorical target variable with `sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder`